# Помогите разобраться с формулировкой задачи

Tags: c++, c

Написать функцию для произвольного двухмерного классического (не свободного) массива с использованием индексов. Прототип функции должен выглядеть приблизительно следующим образом:

```
int Func( int * Array, int Dim1, int Dim2, ...).
```

Методические указания решения задачи приведены в лекции 4 (разработка функции print_arr).

> **Второй вариант функции должен являться чисто формальным**
>   преобразованием выражений с индексами
>   в выражения с указателями (как это
>   делает компилятор).

Определить количество положительныых элементов главной диагонали
превышающих заданное значение

Интересует объяснение к второму варианту
как понимать чистоформальное преобразование с индексами в вырежения с указателями?
как это должно выглядить?

Comment: @Анатолийй, если для главной диагонали матрицы с известной размерностью (N x N) Вы напишите

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       if (a[i][i] > 0 && a[i][i] > v) 
          n++;

то в Вашем случае (если Dim1 -- количество строк, а Dim2 --  количество столбцов, или что то же самое, элементов в строке)

    for(int i = 0; i < min(Dim1, Dim2); i++) {
       int x = *(Array + i * Dim2 + i) // просто, что бы в if-е поменьше писать
       if (x > 0 && x > v)
         n++;
    }

получается что-то такое  (перебираем те же Array[i][i]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это значит, что для одномерного массива вместо `arr[i]` нужно писать

```
*(arr + i)
```

для двумерного `arr[i][j]` нужно писать

```
*( *(arr + i) + j)
```

для трехмерного arr[i][j][k]` будет

```
*( *( *(arr + i) + j) + k)
```

и так далее, рекурсивно оборачивая выражение до нужной размерности.

Comment: Эээ... массив же передан как `int*`, а не `int[...][...][...]...`. То есть надо `arr + dim2 * (dim1 * i + j) + k`.

Comment: @VladD
Опять я на это попался) Да, я все о jagged array, в случае с цельным куском памяти истина будет к вам ближе.